# Android cannot find symbol variable error

Tags: java, android

I'm following this [example](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) from http://developer.android.com to build a simple app to find the last known location. I get the `cannot find symbol variable` error for the variables, `mLastLocation`, `mLatitudeText` and `mLongitudeText`  in the following code snippet in the activity file:

```
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }
```

The variables aren't defined in the sample too. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the two mentioned TextView widgets in your UI or main_activity.xml file

```
....
<TextView
    android:text="-"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    />

  <TextView
    android:text="-"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textview2"
    />
....
```

..and then reference them in the code in your MainActivity.java file.
For mLastLocation, well it needs to be **Location** type, since the function **[getLastLocation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)** returns a **Location** type.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

Location mLastLocation;
TextView mLatitudeText,mLongitudeText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   mLatitudeText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
   mLongitudeText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview2); 
 }


...
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The link to the android developers website isn't pointing to a specific tutorial, so I can speak directly to that one. However, the `mLatitudeText` and `mLongitudeText` appear to be simple `TextView`s. If they aren't created, you can just create them and add them to the activity yourself.